# How can i make a Scfilter that can filter string and number values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

Javascript(coffescript):

```
.filter "scFilter", () ->
  (collection, search) ->
    return collection unless search
    regexp = createAccentRegexp(search)
    doesMatch = (txt) -> (''+txt).match(regexp)
    collection.filter (el) ->
      if typeof el == 'object'
        return true for att, value of el when typeof(value) is 'string' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt '$$hashKey'
      else  
        doesMatch(el)
```

I wanna change this line "**return true for att, value of el when typeof(value) is 'string' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt '$$hashKey'**" to make is possible to filter number and string values.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be easily answered by fixing the conditional logic, but then it will get difficult to read. Instead I'll show you some nicer ways of expressing the condition which you are running in a loop:

```
return true for att, value of el when typeof(value) is 'string' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt '$$hashKey'
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
for att, value of el
  return true if typeof(value) is 'string' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt '$$hashKey'
```

The `doSomething() for X of/in Y when condition` syntax is a shorthand which I would suggest only to use if the function fits on a single line without becoming unwieldy.

The above could be made a little more legible by skipping over any fields which you don't want to check:

```
for att, value of el
  # first filter out any unwanted values
  continue unless typeof(value) is 'string'
  continue if att is '$$hashKey'
  # Then run you function for checking for matching search terms 
  return true if and doesMatch(value)
```

Now to extend it to search for numbers is much easier:

```
for att, value of el
  # first filter out any unwanted values
  continue unless typeof(value) in ['string', 'number']
  continue if att is '$$hashKey'
  # Then run you function for checking for matching search terms 
  return true if and doesMatch(value)
```

Take a look at [the little book of coffeescript](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/), specifically the [idioms](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/04_idioms.html) as they explain a lot of how comprehensions work in coffeescript

Comment: It didnt work, maybe something is written wrong, are these lines correct? "**continue if att if '$$hashKey**'" / "**continue unless typeof(value) in ['string', 'number']**"

Comment: the line "** continue unless typeof(value) in ['string' , 'number']**" did not work aswell, only think that is working is this example:

    `return true for att, value of el when typeof(value) is 'string' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt '$$hashKey' and att isnt 'icon
'
    return true for att, value of el when typeof(value) is 'number' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt 'id'`

Comment: There was a typo, it should have read `if att is `$$hashKey``